# How can I create a custom type to always represent an array of some basic type with a set number of elements?

Tags: c#, custom-type

I'd like to know how I'd create this possible type. The idea would be to have a type that represents an integer array of only 3 elements, yet be accessible using brackets just like any ordinary array.

I'm essentially wanting to convert

```
int[] myArray = new int[3];
```

into

```
myType myArray = new myType();
```

Then access myArray as such, just like if it was created using the original int[] process:

```
myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
myArray[2] = 3;
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: why would you want to do this? Ever thought of using the List<T> generic type? you can also still use the indexer to access an element

Comment: You can add an indexer to any object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: As @david said you need to implement an indexer on `myArray` http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vivek4u_swamy/indexers-and-properties/

Comment: @David Exactly what I was looking for but didn't know to search for it. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [add an indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) to any object.  For example (directly from MSDN):

```
class SampleCollection<T>
{
    // Declare an array to store the data elements. 
    private T[] arr = new T[100];

    // Define the indexer, which will allow client code 
    // to use [] notation on the class instance itself. 
    // (See line 2 of code in Main below.)         
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            // This indexer is very simple, and just returns or sets 
            // the corresponding element from the internal array. 
            return arr[i];
        }
        set
        {
            arr[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the object internally manages an array of 100 elements.  In your case you'd just use 3 elements.  The usage of that object would then resemble what you're looking for:

```
// Declare an instance of the SampleCollection type.
SampleCollection<string> stringCollection = new SampleCollection<string>();

// Use [] notation on the type.
stringCollection[0] = "Hello, World";
System.Console.WriteLine(stringCollection[0]);
```

Note also that the indexer is *explicitly* defined as an `int` in the example.  You can use other types for indexers as well.  (`string` is a common alternative.)

Comment: A constructor would be useful:

    `public SampleCollection<T>(int capacity)
    {
        arr = new T[capacity];
    }`

Comment: @khlr: If the OP wants the consuming code to define capacity, definitely.  If, on the other hand, the OP wants a custom object which internally *always* creates a 3-element array, then no.

Comment: that's right. I just wondered why you put 100 in this sample.